# mysql select all - check all columns for null with ifnull

Tags: mysql, select, null, ifnull

I want to return all columns, and anywhere there's a NULL to say 'hey' instead.

But this doesn't work

```
SELECT IFNULL(*, 'hey') FROM $table
```

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: In this case the syntax used is obviously invalid, so one can infer the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do this one column at a time.

Functions do not generally take `*` as an argument.

```
select ifnull(col1, 'hey'), . . .
```